# ScreenUtil parameters are not defined

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I followed an old flutter tutorial
with changing all old dependencies which caused a lot of errors ofc,
I was able to fix all of them only this one:
after changing the version of `screenutil` from `0.4.2` to `5.0.2`
I got this error: (and other errors that I fixed already)

```
No named parameter with the name 'width'.
ScreenUtil.init(context, width: 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: true);
```

on this line of code

```
ScreenUtil.init(context, width: 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: true);
```

I'm a newbie in flutter and dart so even after reading the documentation of `screenutil 5.0.2` I still don't understand what changes I have to do to fix the error.
What I undestood after reading the doc is: that the `ScreenUtil` object doesn't have `width`,`height` and `allowFontScaling` properties anymore. I think now it takes (`designSize`, `builder`, `orientation` and `splitScreenMode`).
So I need a way to convert my old line of code

```
ScreenUtil.init(context, width: 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: true);
```

to a newer one with the newer properties. 
help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just coppied some lines from the documentation and it seems to be working just fine
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil

```
//ScreenUtil.init(context, 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: true); 
// == 

    ScreenUtil.init(BoxConstraints(
        maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
    ),
    designSize: const Size(750, 1334),
    minTextAdapt: true,
    );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).